# How to make Folder path in android studio using Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a folder is not exists at a particular location in my android device...Here is my code... Its not generating any error but also not creating any folder...

```
package com.example.akshaykumar.latlong;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Double latToCompare=0.0, longToCompare=0.0;
    float shortestDistance = 0.0f;
    Boolean isDistanceComparedFirstTime = true;
    Boolean isFirstRowInCSV1 = true, isFirstRowInCSV2 = true;
    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        createDirIfNotExists("/LatLongFiles"); ////////////////
 }

    public static boolean createDirIfNotExists(String path) {
        boolean ret = true;

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (!file.mkdirs()) {
                ret = false;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

createDirIfNotExists("/LatLongFiles");   This is the particular code that not creating any folder.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permission declared? Also try removing the slash in the directory name.

Comment: Hey, can you tell me how to check its permission and i think slash does'nt have any effect on it... Actually when i connected my android device to my computer its not showing it as removable disk also..

Comment: I currently cannot as I am busy; that is something that searching on the Internet will quickly find. You need to declare the appropriate permission in your AndroidManifest.xml. Also, try it with the slash, and ensure that the Android device can both mount and access the device itself (i.e. no driver, hardware, or filesystem issues)

Comment: @AkshayKumar take a look in [this saving file in android training](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: 'Its not generating any error but also not creating any folder... '. And what does that function return? Do not use that slash.

Comment: Guys my problem got solved.. The only problem is with its permission.. I changed its permission in its manifest file and its working fine now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this into your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```